# Without JavaScript, can I show a different text when a longer one won't fit?

Tags: html, css

#### What I'm trying to do

I have a size-limited box which is supposed to contain some text:

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Some text goes here.
</div>
```

However, if the text becomes too long to fit in the box, I want to replace that text with a different, shorter version, which I have prepared in advance.

So for example, if I want to populate two boxes with these two names:

```
Short version      Long version
------------------------------------------------------------
Rudolf E. Raspe    Rudolf Erich Raspe
Baron Munchausen   Hieronymus Karl Friedrich von Munchhausen
```

Then the first box will contain "Rudolf Erich Raspe" since it's short enough to fit inside, but the second box will contain "Baron Munchausen" since the Baron's full name is too long to fit.

How can I set up such a box, using just HTML5 and CSS3? Browser compatibility is important but, I don't need to accommodate really old versions or Internet Explorer prior to 11.

#### Alternatives

I can choose any of the standard options for handling too-long text - letting it overflow, or cutting it via `overflow: hidden`, or adding scrollbars, or adding ellipses, or any of the other standard solutions. But since I already have short versions of every possible text there, I would like to use these instead.

I can do this in JavaScript by, for example, using a wrapper and comparing its size with the box's. But I would like a non-JavaScript solution, if possible.

#### What I've tried

So far I thought about making the text somehow push itself down if it's too long (some combination of white-space and word-wrap?), making the container overflow: hidden to hide it when it's down there, and placing the short version of the text behind it, but I couldn't get it to work while still allowing the text to occupy more than one line.

Another approach is to place an element with the short text just below the element with the long text, and use some transform which makes that short element take over when it's pushed down too much... But I couldn't get it to work either.

So... any other ideas?

Comment: You can even do that using CSS using `:before` or `:after` with attribute `content` and using `@media`.

Comment: Why without JavaScript though?

Comment: Yes I was thinking if some obscure combination of `overflow:hidden` and `position:absolute` might be feasible, but I'm sure it;s not. Wouldn't just showing the short version and having the long one in a `title=""` attribute be better all round?

Comment: @DenysSéguret Doesn't look like a duplicate to me, plus that question is quite old, there may be a new way to do it.

Comment: Would something like this suit you ? https://jsfiddle.net/17swppdL/

Comment: @Oak Is this when the browser is resized, or if the element is resized?

Comment: @Elfayer You've precomputed the size, this defeats the purpose of styling

Comment: @Elfayer your solution depends on the width of the viewport, while I want to choose based on the length of the text. As Denys mentioned, I don't have the length of the text pre-calculated in advance.

Comment: @JacquesMarais I'm not sure I understand the question. Neither will be resized, and I know the size of the box in advance. What I want is to choose the text based on whether it will fit into the box.

Comment: @Oak Oh I understand now. Still, why no JavaScript?

Comment: @JacquesMarais In some situations Javascript runs late on that page, and I would prefer avoiding text changing after it's rendered. In other situations the Javascript runs fine. I will absolutely use Javascript if I have no other option, but I was just hoping an expert might be able to provide a clean Javascript-less solution for this that will make my life easier.

Comment: Meanwhile, I've found a [related question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18817464/242762), with an innovative solution but which only applies for single-lines boxes.

Comment: @JacquesMarais JavaScript is disabled in every browser in the world until your JS downloads.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a way... kinda...

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 18px;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

span {  position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; max-height: 36px;  }
em { position: absolute; width: 100%; top: 18px; left: 0; background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="box">
   <span> 
     This text fits
     <em>fallback text</em>
   </span>
</div>

<div class="box">
   <span> 
     Huge text that doesn't fit and it's more than 3 lines. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
     <em>fallback text</em>
   </span>
</div>

<div class="box">
   <span> 
     This text doesn't fit
     <em>fallback text</em>
   </span>
</div>
```

It's not a very pretty solution, but hey it's something. :)

Comment: Oh this is beautiful :-) would it be possible to tweak it to work when the box is higher, specifically when it can hold two lines? I tried but weren't able to do that without the text being bottom-aligned.

Comment: @oak only two lines or one line as well ? Because there is a way to make it for two lines, but I'm not sure that it will be able to support one line as well: https://jsfiddle.net/z0tcL44p/3/ ( at least can't think it at the moment )

Comment: I am looking at the code, still have no clue how it works o.0 Mind explaining?

Comment: @Dellirium sure. The magic numbers are `bottom: 0` for the `span` and `top: 18px` for the `em`. The span is set to `position: absolute` and the `em` inside it is position below the first text line with `top: 18px`. Once the `span` increase it's text it's height becomes 36px for 2 lines or more ( that's why there is `max-height: 36px;` ) and since the `span` is positioned at `bottom: 0` it increases it's height from bottom to top, meaning that if we swap the `bottom` property with `top` it will be `top: -18px` and that's why you see the em.

Comment: @Oak Warning: by using this solution you are breaking the ability to copy&paste the text. When the user tries to select *fallback text* it will end up selecting the long text too.

Comment: OK, I've finally managed it! https://jsfiddle.net/c95Ln9q3/ shows how this neat trick can be performed with boxes taller than one line.

Comment: @drip bonus points for creativity, i'd never use it as I think its a bad thing but it solves the issue exactly as described, +1

Answer (score 5):

I've done something similar by using `overflow:hidden` and floating `divs`.

```html
<div style="overflow:hidden;height:1.2em;">
  <div style="float:left">Rudolph</div>
  <div style="float:right">Raspe</div>
  Erich
</div>
```

So, on a small block you'll get *Rudolph Raspe*, on a big - *Rudolph Erich Raspe*.

Obviously, it's not very universal, but in some specific cases it can be used.

Answer (score 3):

I was having some fun with a single-line solution, I realise the multi-line solution may be a better fit for the OP. I'm just sticking it up here in case it's useful to anyone. I ran a quick test on the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, IE and Edge, and it seems to work fine everywhere. I've added some fixed width boxes to the example, but it actually works with a dynamic box width as well.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  /* extraneous CSS added for sample clarity only */
  font-family: Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 3px;  
}

div > span {
  background-color: #EFF0F1;
  float: left;
}

div::before {
  content: "\00a0";
}

div::after {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #EFF0F1;
}
```

```html
<div title="Rudolf E. Raspe">
  <span>Rudolf Erich Raspe</span>
</div>
<div title="Baron Munchausen">
  <span>Hieronymus Karl Friedrich von Munchhausen</span>
</div>
<div title="Rudolf E. Raspe" style="width:400px;">
  <span>Rudolf Erich Raspe</span>
</div>
<div title="Baron Munchausen" style="width:400px;">
  <span>Hieronymus Karl Friedrich von Munchhausen</span>
</div>
<div title="Rudolf E. Raspe" style="width:200px;">
  <span>Rudolf Erich Raspe</span>
</div>
<div title="Baron Munchausen" style="width:200px;">
  <span>Hieronymus Karl Friedrich von Munchhausen</span>
</div>
<div title="Rudolf E. Raspe" style="width:120px;">
  <span>Rudolf Erich Raspe</span>
</div>
<div title="Baron Munchausen" style="width:120px;">
  <span>Hieronymus Karl Friedrich von Munchhausen</span>
</div>
```

It works by creating three elements inside a containing `div`.

- An invisible `div::before` pseudo element with the single purpose of just being there to make sure the second element (the `span`) isn't the first element on the line
- A `span` containing the longer version of the text
- A `div::after` pseudo element containing the shorter version of the text

The containing `div` is set to `position: relative` to create a new block formatting context inside itself.

The `div::after` pseudo element is set to `position: absolute` with `top: 0; left: 0;` set to ensure it sits at the same position as the `span`,  while `right: 0; bottom: 0;` ensure the element is always as large as its containing element (the `div`). `z-index: -1;` ensures the element sits behind the `span`.

Both the `div::before` and the `span` are rendered as inline elements. As soon as the `div::before` and the `span` together become too wide to fit snugly on one line, the whole `span` moves down to the next line, revealing the `div::after` which was hiding behind it.

The only reason for having the `div::before` there is to ensure the `span` moves down to the next line, it wouldn't do so if it was the first inline element.

The `overflow: hidden; line-height: 1.2em; height: 1.2em;` on the containing `div` ensure the `span` is invisible as soon as it jumps to the next line.

Comment: I'm struggling to see how this works, could you put more explanation in your answer?

Comment: @Pureferret - That's done, let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Now I understand this I can appreciate how clever it is, and how neat. +1'd and starred the question. I'm sure this will come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

**Pure CSS Solution:**

Using:

```
<div class="box" data-shortname="Baron Munchausen">
    Hieronymus Karl Friedrich von Munchhausen
</div>
```

For ages I tried to do something using `box::after` and `z-index`:

```
box {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}

box::after {
    content: attr(data-shortname);
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I came up empty-handed - though you *could* use a `@media query` with the setup above to apply a positive or negative `z-index` to `box::after`.

(If the `box::after` `z-index` is positive, the shortname displays, otherwise the longer name displays.)

---

**JavaScript Solution:**

So here is a JavaScript-based solution using `data-*` after all:

```js
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');

for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    if (boxes[i].textContent.length > 20) {
        boxes[i].textContent = boxes[i].dataset.shortname;
    }
}
```

```css
.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" data-shortname="Rudolf E. Raspe">
    Rudolf Erich Raspe
</div>

<div class="box" data-shortname="Baron Munchausen">
    Hieronymus Karl Friedrich von Munchhausen
</div>
```

Comment: Question specifically asked for a solution *without* client-side scripting.

Comment: **OP:** _"I can do this in Javascript by, for example, using a wrapper and comparing its size with the box's. But I would like a non-Javascript solution, if possible."_ So I have shown the limits of a non-javascript solution employing `data-*` and then I have shown a javascript solution employing `data-*`.

Comment: But your non-Javascript "solution" is not a solution - you say "I came up empty-handed".

Comment: I did not mean "empty-handed" to be taken literally. It's supposed to be tongue in cheek - I am sure you can see how the CSS would work. Certainly in any conditional environment (such as `@media queries`) it is a solution which works perfectly. I am at a loss to think of any other pure CSS context which introduces conditionality. If you have one, I will be happy to amend the first part of the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not a true answer, but rather an alternative. Is there any reason you can't use text-overflow?

```
.box span {
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Helpful link:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/

Comment: I guess that's because it doesn't "replace the text".

Comment: As I've written in the question, I can do this - but I prefer to replace the text instead. Read my "Alternatives" section.

Comment: Yes, thats what I thought but I don't think there is a way without Javascript. CSS doesn't really have logic. Which is why I love it :)

Comment: Reread the question. I skimmed past the ellipsis part. Sorry bout that! When reading I was looking for text-overflow property. I would think if there was a css there would be duplicated content which isn't always the best.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a lot of ways this 'could' be done if the sizes and patterns were constant...but in your example with the names, the short text is not even part of the long text in both cases, it's a different string entirely in the second example, which limits your options in terms of showing/hiding/overlapping

If you can identify a consistent screen size at which you are going to swap from short to long, you can use `data-` attributes and CSS `content` along with `@media` queries.

Considering the variables, I would suggest using something like the example below to change all the items to the short version at a moderate breakpoint, and then use a method like adding an ellipsis to handle any longer values that would wrap in either short or long versions.

```
<div class="box">
  <p class="text-container" data-short-version="Rudolf E. Raspe" data-long-version="Rudolf Erich Raspe"></p>
  <p class="text-container" data-short-version="Baron Munchausen" data-long-version="Hieronymus Karl Friedrich von Munchhausen"></p>
</div>

.text-container:before {
  content:attr(data-short-version);}

.text-container {  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-size:40px;
  margin:0px;}

@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
  .text-container:before {
    content:attr(data-long-version);
  }
}
```

Example here: http://codepen.io/ryantdecker/pen/wWPJNA

Comment: But your solution switches the content based on the screen width; what I'm looking for is switching based on whether the content fits inside a container.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I stated that in the answer, in fact.  If there's not a responsive aspect to your container (if it's always 100px, no matter the device size), this won't work, but often a containing div will be sized relative to the screen in responsive sites, so this may help others in a similar situation but needing a responsive solution.  While I don't believe you can do exactly what you are asking for with just CSS, this is an example of what CSS actually can do, depending on your exact situation/needs